Issue with ClerkJS auth() and currentUser() Methods in Server Components & Server Actions in Latest Next.js Version
I followed the clerkjs docs and this is the middleware.ts file :
middleware.ts file
and this is the code for the page.tsx which is server component
import { getUserByClerkId } from "@/lib/actions/user/user.get.action";
import { TUser } from "@/types/models";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";

const StoriesPage = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) return redirect("/sign-in");

  let user: TUser | null = null;

  try {
    const { statusCode, message, data } = await getUserByClerkId(userId);

    if (statusCode !== 200) throw new Error(message);

    user = data as TUser;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  return <div>StoriesPage</div>;
};

export default StoriesPage;


now the problem as u see when i try to acces to the loggedin user from a server component (page.tsx in this case) or a server action using the clerk helpers auth() or currentUser() i keep getting this error
enter image description here
if someone is using the latest versions of both clerk & next and he faced the same issue and fix it please let us now about the solution

I'm getting the same error and I'm having trouble figuring out why. Did you figure this out? It just started randomly without me making any updates to my application.

I'm not the expert here but I would suggest checking the terminal. It should say compiling /middleware or else check the exact naming.
Something like this terminal snapshot
Also there are some breaking changes for upgrade in clerk Clerk Upgrade guide

module not found error always pop up i think it's because clerk updated and next.js also i old version it works

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
